# Does Tor block network administrators from determining sites accessed/data downloaded?

Tags: configuration, website, server-administration

If I am on a network in which the admins monitor sites accessed and possibly data downloaded; can I be confident that Tor would block them from doing this? Are there any exceptions - for example if there are too few people using Tor on the network, or can Tor be blocked without me being able to tell? (note they don't have the right to stop me having Tor on my computer)

I understand from research that there is no way I can actually stop someone from figuring out I am using Tor.

Thanks for any answers on this - I have been researching this stuff but don't understand all the technical details involved.

Also, if there are answers to this which are bad for my privacy but have a solution I can install, that would be highly appreciated.

Note - have Tor browser 5.5.3 for Windows installed, without anything else added on top (i.e. using standard version from installation)

Answer (score 1):

Tor won't prohibit them from having their intentions, but it will disarm a lot of their tools and approaches : they will simply be unable to circumvert your traffic in many ways and using certain methods. The exceptions you're concerned about do not exist, but if in your locality will be more people using Tor - a Tor network will work for all of you a bit faster due to local mirrors of V2Dir/HSDir on a local nodes. Go ahead and welcome to the Tor world! feel free to ask further questions

Answer (score 1):

If they're only looking at your network traffic then they would know you are using Tor.

They wouldn't be able to know what your traffic contained or where it was sent to or received from but they could *estimate* how much traffic you've sent and received and when.

This all depends on you *owning* the hardware *and* operating system that Tor Browser is running on. If your device is part of a *"Windows Domain"* or similar then the *"Domain Administrator"* can make you run what is essentially malware and see everything that is happening on the system without exception.